# Continued: Handling 'Pear Mail to text/SMS' truncated messages

Tags: php, email, foreach, pear, explode

I am using the PEAR mail library to process mail on my PHP site.

For long messages going to txt/SMS, I am breaking the message and looping through the mail() script in order to provide the entire message to recipient.

MY CODE:

```
$xi=1;
$x = 125;
if (strlen($txtbody)>$x) {
 $bodyparts = explode("\n", wordwrap($txtbody, $x));
 foreach($bodyparts as $bodypart) { 
  $bodypart='(#'.$xi.') '.$bodypart;   
  $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $bodypart);
  $xi++; 
 }
} else {
 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $txtbody);
}
```

MY ISSUE:

my messages aren't being received in proper order.

I am numbering each message segment to see if there is any rhyme or reason, but not finding anything.

- is this a message size issue? (smaller messages travel faster?)
- should I delay the loop? (I really don't want to slow this down though...)

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: my experience with sms, you cant ever be sure of delivery order, its outside your control. who is your sms gateway? mine spits long messages for me so i don't have to.

Comment: gateway...? I am sending the messages directly to the recipients ('phone number')@('provider').com. I personally have verizon, and long messages get cut. I am sending to only approx. 10 people and there are I think 4 different cellular providers between them.

Comment: i would never bother , those services are-very low priority for the provider, have very poor reliability, if you want to be sure the msg arrives, use a gateway